# Bootstrap div Reset

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to understand how to reset boostraps columns.

If I did this:

```
Col-md-6
Col-md-4
```

How would I then create a new row where the columns start back at 1 and not 11. 
I don't understand where (or if) I should use clearfix

Many thanks
David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the third col-md is greater than 2, Bootstrap makes automatically a new row, because (4 + 6 + (x > 2)) > 12. Than you **don't need** a **clearfix**.

If the third column is col-md-1 or col-md-2, you can **use a clearfix** to clear the *current flow* and set the column into a new line:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        col-md-4
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        col-md-6
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <!-- New row -->
    <div class="col-md-2">
        col-md-2
    </div>
</div>
```

New line **automatically** (4 + 6 + 6 = 16) > 12:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        col-md-4
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        col-md-6
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        col-md-6
    </div>
</div>
```

Clearfix can also be used to show columns only at a specific device width, for example:

```
<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block">
    only visible in xs and a block element
</div>
```